# Find implementation of interface under cursor in current class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Slightly different versions of this questions don't seem to address my problem, F12/Ctrl-F12 is not what I'm looking for.

When editing a large class that implements an interface defined elsewhere, I'd like to jump to all the places in the file where a function of the interface is implemented:

```
class VeryLargeClass : IInterfaceInOtherFile
{
  // lots of code

  // ..... I want to jump here
  public FirstFunctionOfIInterfaceInOtherFile() {}

  // more code

  // ..... then I want to jump here
  public SecondFunctionOfIInterfaceInOtherFile() {}
}
```

Imagine the cursor is on `IInterfaceInOtherFile` I'd like to find all the places in the current file where `IInterfaceInOtherFile` is implemented.

Another alternative would be a display mode in ClassView where I can see whether a function in a class is an implemented interface, override from the base class or specific to the class.

Is that possible, maybe with a plugin?

Comment: Have you tried hitting `F12` or `Ctrl+F12`? Those are the `Go To Definition` and `Go To Implementation` shortcuts

Comment: Yes, see comment for Olivier's answer.

Comment: The reason you're getting answers/comments about F12/Ctrl+F12 is that you're asking where an interface gets implemented, and Ctrl+F12 is the command to do that. The general "best practice" is to have one class per file, so finding "all the places in the current file" where it's implemented can strike people as a bit odd. If you do indeed have multiple implementations in a single file, the way to find the implementations is to highlight the interface name and simply Ctrl-F and start searching...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think I didn't ask my question properly. Imagine a single class MyClass in file MyClass.cs with an interface MyInterface declared in a second file. Now I want to find all the places in MyClass.cs where MyClass implements a function of MyInterface.

Comment: @AndrewQueisser update your question. Comments can be deleted at any time and most people don't read them.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017 (did not test in other versions) you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> or right click on the interface name and choose "Go To Implementation". If there are several implementations, you will get a list of implementations to choose from.

The same mechanism exists for individual properties and methods of the interface.

Note that from an implementation (or anywhere else), you can "Go To Definition" with <kbd>F12</kbd> or through the context menu. With <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> (or context menu) you can "Peek Definition". Form there you can then go to the implementation(s).

Comment: Yes, but what I'm looking for is to go to the specific implementation in the current class I'm editing. It's more complex since it would require some kind of search mechanism for the individual functions, in the current class, that implement the interface.

Comment: The same navigation functions work for members of a type.